# App crash when using UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

There's a sign-out button in the page, when clicked I want to post the ok-cancel tips, here’s my code:

```
UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Tips" message:@"Sign out?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
}];
[alertVC addAction:cancelAction];
UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}];
[alertVC addAction:okAction];
[self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

App crashes with error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller: should have parent view controller: but requested parent is:'
I copy the code into a simple demo. it works well, but it crash in my project. And I try using UIAlertView which is deprecated,and it’s Ok. Any problem with my using the UIAlertController

Comment: From which control are you presenting uialertcontroller?

Comment: my custom UIViewController

Comment: do you get what requested parent is in exception?

Comment: reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7fbbc0c315a0> should have parent view controller:<MyViewController: 0x7fbbc20d8200> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7fbbc1855000>'

Comment: You should provide more context for the presenting since it seems that you are presenting from some control.

Answer (score 0):

As from exception i think your view controller's hierarchy is not correct.
So this is the simplest way to show alertviewcontroller.

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:yourAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Or get your app top most viewController and then present alertViewController on that viewController. Here is the method to find top most viewController in your app.

```
- (UIViewController*) topMostController
{
    UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

    while (topController.presentedViewController) {
        topController = topController.presentedViewController;
    }

    return topController;
}
```

Comment: I try the code in a simple demo, it works. But get crash error with UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency in my project

Comment: do you try to get top most viewController from the method and present the alertController on that viewController?

Comment: the top most viewController method returns MyViewController, end up with the same error.

Comment: from where you load your viewController XIB or Storyboard?

Comment: I don't use a XIB or Storyboard, the view is inherited from UIViewController

Comment: can you explain your hierarchy of viewControllers a bit. That how they present or push. And is there any NavigationController is a rootController or not?

Comment: NavigationController(root vc of the key window) > ViewController A (root VC of Nav) > push > ViewController B > present >MyViewController, I use the same hierarchy in a simple demo to present a AlertController, it's ok. guess it's cause by some other property in  MyViewController

Comment: i think your MyViewController is dismissed before presenting the alertController. and this is the issue. Try to dismiss MyViewController in the alertController action.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. MyViewController was dismissed by system when trying to present an AlertController